# Unselecting a select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two select list one a list of teams the other a list of players. The list of players changes depending on the selection of the team. I want to have whatever player was selected in the player list get unselected if the team in the team list is reselected. I have:

```
 $("#playerList select option").prop("selected", false);
```

Which deselects the player but it only does it once i mouse over the list. How do i have this change appear right away?

Comment: Can you post some code, or a jsfiddle with the minimum code needed to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Sometimes you need to use trickery to force a redraw. Maybe try setting and unsetting some CSS property. Also, do you have a default setting? If so, it would be better to set the list to your default, like a `"Choose one..."` option. That way you can explicitly set the value of the `select` using `.val()`.

Comment: `$('#playerList select').val('')` should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( '#TeamList' ).on( 'change', function ()
                {

                    if ( condition1==true )
                    {

                        $( "#playerList option[value='1']" ).remove();
                        $( "#playerList option[value='2']" ).remove();

    //.................... and so on (Remove the items you dont need and add new items)
                        $( "#playerList" ).append( '<option value="3" style="background-color:#A9F5A9">Player new1</option>' );
                        $( "#playerList " ).append( '<option value="4" style="background-color:#A9F5A9">Player new2</option>' );


                    }
                    else
                    {

                        $( "#playerList option[value='3']" ).remove(); //Remove the items
                        $( "#playerList option[value='4']" ).remove();

                        $( "#playerList " ).append( '<option value="1">Player1</option>' );
                        $( "#playerList " ).append( '<option value="2">player2</option>' );

                    }
                } );
```

Comment: First of all there's a much simpler solution as @Dogoku pointed out in the answer above. Secondly the `live()` method is deprecated; use `on()` instead.